# How can i Obfuscate a monogame windows8 metro app?

Tags: windows-8, obfuscation, monogame

I have a windows 8 metro game (using monogame) that i developed and plan to submit to windows 8 app store and i wish to obfuscate it. How can i do it? Will obfuscation cause runtime errors?

Comment: Have you tried any programs that are out there already? My company uses Eziris for a desktop program

Comment: My recommendation would be: don't bother. If you think it will make your app more secure then there are plenty of examples out there to show that security by obscurity doesn't work. And since it's a game it is unlikely that you want to protect some new fancy trademark algorithm from reverse engineering (which only works in rare cases). Chances are nobody cares about your code and you're just giving yourself lots of work and headache when you get your first error report and try to evaluate an obfuscated stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm). It has a very decent GUI, a great support team, and most importantly both Visual Studio integration and support for Obfuscating Windows 8 Store apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Manco .NET Obfuscator](http://www.mancosoftware.com/licensing/index.htm). Version 4.5 supports obfuscating of the .NET Windows 8 Store applications.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [babel obfuscator](http://babelobfuscator.blogspot.pt/2012/10/babel-obfuscator-6000-released.html).
The obfuscator usually "just" makes your code unreadable, alone it won't cause any runtime exceptions but if some occurs (due to an app problem) you probably won't be able to track the error (because everything is obfuscated).

PS: Google is our friend